# What is the best way to inspect a running Ruby process

Tags: ruby, debugging

I was having problems with a Ruby process that was running wild.

What are the best ways to inspect such a process for debugging purposes?

I found a nice article about [using GDB](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/9/22/inspecting-a-live-ruby-process) to inspect it.

What are you using for this purpose, do you have any good resources to read?

Comment: Try rbtrace ? https://github.com/tmm1/rbtrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a good way is beginning by the Tracer lib

use it with

```
ruby -rtracer
```

or 
    strace

on Linux with -f  flag, to following forks

```
truss
```

on BSD with the same flag

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this, but saw this new library yesterday [get_process_mem](https://github.com/schneems/get_process_mem).

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in current_process_memory_size you can implement method #memstats (thanks to [Avdi Grimm](http://about.avdi.org/) and his [rubytapas](http://www.rubytapas.com/) lessons).

```
require 'csv'

def memstats
  size = `ps -o size= #{$$}`.strip.to_i
  p "Size: #{size}"
end


memstats                        # => "Size: 5168"
CSV.open('simple.csv', headers: true) do |csv|
  visitors = csv.each           
  memstats                      # => "Size: 5170"
  p visitors.count{|v| v} # => 168

end
memstats                        # => "Size: 5168"
```

$$ is a [special variable](http://ruby.wikia.com/wiki/Special_variable) in ruby, which allows you to get a numeric process ID of the current process